# Create SQL Server Compact Edition SP1 Database (with SP2 already installed)

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have created a Software Solution with a Compact Edition 3.5 SP2 Database. Unfortunately i have discovered after finalizing the Solution, that some Endusers are unwilling to install SP2 (they already have SP1 installed).

Since there are no restrictions to SP1 which would affect me, i suggested to downgrade the whole solution to SP1 rather then making different deployment packages, as SP2 is downward-compatible.

Unfortunately i have a huge Problem:
I cannot create a SQL Server CE 3.5 SP1 Datebase on any of my Computers, since i have automatic Windows Updates activated and i have SP2 installed everywhere.

The Question is simple: How can i create a SQL Server CE 3.5 SP1 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from som Sync Framework related changes, there is no difference in database format between 3.5 SP1 and 3.5 SP2

Comment: what does that mean? Do i need another Version of Sync-Framework? do i have to change something in my code?

Comment: The Sync Framework system tables have changed in SP2 - are you using Sync Framework?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. also, this is the first time i tried to use. of course i immediatley ran into the only problem;-). so can i solve this problem by installing specific versions of sync framework? im syncing download only from 1 central server, 1 database, several tables.